# Adding icons to my website

Tags: css, icons

How do I use icons from sites like The Noun Project and Font Awesome on my website? I know how to download them but how do I locate where the icons are stored in the CSS folder and use the downloaded one?

I'm editing from a template so I have to use the same icon name, just save over it I assume...

PS: I'm using sublime text.

Comment: Look at the "Get Started" section of the official website.
http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to read the [Get Started](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) section first.

> Using CSS:
>
> Copy the entire `font-awesome` directory into your project.
>   In the `<head>` of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css. 
>   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Check out the [examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) to start using Font Awesome!

Comment: That worked thanks. They dont have a javascript icon though, I need one. Any recommendations from anyone? And is it the same procedure as Font Awesome ones where I copy the directory into the head of my HTML file?